# how to store name of the file when using react-admin ImageInput component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I can't find documentation how to store file name when using react-admin ImageInput component.

So this is what I use now:

```
<ImageInput
        multiple
        source="pictures"
        label="Related pictures"
        accept="image/*"
        maxSize={5000000}
      >
        <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
      </ImageInput>
```

So when it uploads data to firebase storage the picture name is indexed 0 1 2 etc... how to store it's real name for example imagename.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [react-admin-firebase](https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase)? If so, there's a config setting to specify that you want filenames rather than the index. From the docs:

```
// Add file name to storage path, when set to true the file name is included in the path
useFileNamesInStorage: false
```